# PureFTPD: ERROR TLS renegociation

Tags: ftps, pureftpd

I set up a server which is working fine. No errors and all services are running well.

I am using ISPConfig 3.1, Ubuntu 18 and Pure-FTPD

When I create a new FTP-user, I have a problem logging in via FTPS.

- I have a valid certificate
- Pure-FTPD is set to use TLS
- Passive FTP is active in Filezilla

**/var/log/syslog** reports the following:

> pure-ftpd: (?@987.654.321.001) [INFO] New connection from 987.654.321.001
>
> pure-ftpd: (?@987.654.321.001) [DEBUG] Command [auth] [TLS]
>
> pure-ftpd: (?@987.654.321.001) [ERROR] TLS renegociation

**Filezilla** reports the following:

> Status:   Auflösen der IP-Adresse für demo.example.de
>
> Status:   Verbinde mit 123.123.123.123:21...
>
> Status:   Verbindung hergestellt, warte auf Willkommensnachricht...
>
> Status:   Initialisiere TLS...
>
> Status:   Überprüfe Zertifikat...
>
> Status:   TLS-Verbindung hergestellt.
>
> Befehl:   USER blubbalo_bill
>
> Fehler:   Konnte vom Socket nicht lesen: **ECONNRESET - Verbindung durch Peer zurückgesetzt** (Connection denied by peer)
>
> Fehler:   **Herstellen der Verbindung zum Server fehlgeschlagen** (Connection failed)

I hope somebody can help me to solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Test FTP client access from an FTP client on the host that is running the FTP service/daemon.  Then test from a remote host on the LAN.  This will show you if you're having a networking related issue.  lftp, curlftpfs, and filezilla can be used in a CLI to test.

Perform a port scan against the FTP host to determine if the firewall rules are configured to allow communication over ports 20, 21 and 990.

Depending on your network configuration your PureFTP server may need to be configured differently such as if you're behind a NAT'ed firewall.
https://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README - Look under "Nat Mode"

In FileZilla prefer the Site Manager versus the QuickConnect.

Try Active mode even if you plan on using passive eventually.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp

Verify Network configuration - https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration

Determine which version of TLS that you're using. TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3.

Double-check that you're not using SFTP which is FTP over an SSH tunnel.

Ensure FileZilla client settings for encryption are "Require explicit FTP over TLS".

Verify TLS version and compatibility of client and server applications.